# Parameter passes NULL value in SOAP service

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, soap

I want to parse soap webservice but when i send parameter, Server gets NULL values i cant understand what is happning there.

I am using SOAP Engine library to parse it.
[SOAPEngine](https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine)

And following is my code.

```
    soap = [[SOAPEngine alloc] init];
 soap.envelope = @"xmlns:tmp=\"http://tempuri.org/\"";

[soap setIntegerValue:50 forKey:@"Celsius"];
[soap requestURL:@"http://w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx" soapAction:@"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit"];
```

Any one plz help me.

Comment: So the request works but without the @"Celsius" param?  That rules out a lot of problems.  And the param in your code is a literal, so what could go wrong with that?  Maybe post the request/headers as received by the server... that will be a big clue.

Comment: i dont know what is happening over there , but when i pass Integer value then sever gets 0, and when I pass string value server gets "NULL".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
SOAPEngine *soap = [[SOAPEngine alloc] init];
    soap.actionNamespaceSlash = YES;

    // w3schools Celsius to Fahrenheit
    [soap setValue:@"30" forKey:@"Celsius"];
    [soap requestURL:@"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"  
        soapAction:@"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit" 
        complete:^(NSInteger statusCode, NSString *stringXML) {

        NSLog(@"Result: %f", [soap floatValue]);

    } failWithError:^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
```

on [GitHub](https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine) you can see more examples

Answer (score 0):

use

[soap setValue:@{@"Celsius":50}];